# How to specify colors for individual points in a scatter plot using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, colors, scatter-plot

My problem is the following.

I have a pandas DataFrame containing the data of a "sample" in the first row and the data of the "controls" on all the other rows.
I would like to have a scatter plot (or any other kind of plot to generalize the question) in which all the "controls" are in one color and the "sample" in another one. How to do that? I have looked in pandas documentation but I couldn’t find anything.

Here is what I have up to now

```
from pandas import *
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = OrderedDict([
                    ('sample', [454, 481, 160, 26, 17]),
                    ('ctrl_1', [454, 470, 101, 10, 8]),
                    ('ctrl_2', [454, 473, 110, 15, 9]),
                    ('ctrl_3', [454, 472, 104, 19, 13]),
                    ('ctrl_4', [454, 472, 105, 16, 13]),
                    ('ctrl_5', [454, 466, 97, 15, 10]),
                    ('ctrl_6', [454, 473, 110, 17, 10]),
                    ('ctrl_7', [454, 465, 99, 15, 11]),
                    ('ctrl_8', [454, 471, 107, 18, 12]),
                    ('ctrl_9', [454, 471, 102, 15, 11]),
                    ('ctrl_10', [454, 472, 116, 14, 9])
                    ])

df = DataFrame.from_dict(mydict,orient='index')
df.columns=['A','B','C','D','E']

df.plot(kind='scatter',x='C',y='E',figsize=(10,10), color='blue')
```

I tried to split the DataFrame in two (controls and sample) and plot one on top of the other but pandas raise an error (TypeError: There is no line property "y") when you try to scatterplot a single point (is it a bug?).

```
sample = df.ix[0]
controls = df.ix[1:]
controls.plot(kind='scatter',x='C',y='E',figsize=(10,10), color='blue')
sample.plot(kind='scatter',x='C',y='E',figsize=(10,10), color='red')
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a Series back from `df.ix[0]`, which [can't be drawn as a scatter plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html). (I guess it could be a valid type in theory, but, as you say, it would only show 1 point.)

If you change your code slightly to make `sample` a DataFrame instead, it works. (I've also put both on the same plot by using the same axes.)

```
sample = df.ix[:1]
controls = df.ix[1:]
ax = controls.plot(kind='scatter',x='C',y='E',figsize=(10,10), color='blue')
sample.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter',x='C',y='E',figsize=(10,10), color='red')
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you. I didn't know that df.ix[0] and df.ix[:1] are different!

Comment: Great! And I've been caught out by the "Is it a DataFrame or Series?" question on many occasions in the past... :)